# how we can insert mongocxx document which available realtime.?

Tags: c++, mongodb, meteor, mongo-cxx-driver

I am inserting images to the mongodb through c++ API as below :

```
   bsoncxx::document::value document = bsoncxx::builder::basic::make_document
                            (kvp("userId", "xZcuQet3QMmS7Q2yc"),
                             kvp("source",encoded_png),
                             kvp("createdAt",bsoncxx::types::b_date(std::chrono::system_clock::now()))
                            );
                    bsoncxx::stdx::optional<mongocxx::result::insert_one> result =
                            coll.insert_one(document.view());
```

Also I am pulling realtime from MeteorJs . I encountered there is a few seconds (5 - 7 sec) delay.

Is it possible that c++ code not flushing the insert ?

How I can do realtime insert with flushing immediately available ?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that c++ code not flushing the insert ?

You can check MongoDB collection whether the document is inserted properly or not. You can use MongoDB Shell or other MongoDB Managers (e.g. [RoboMongo](https://robomongo.org/)) for this regard.

> How I can do realtime insert with flushing immediately available ?

You can [Publish a publication](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html) from the server side of Meteor application and subscribe to it to get the published data immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Change detection is done using oplog tailing. This isn't done in development mode. Updates made from Meteor code trigger updates immediately, but mongo updates from an external source such as Mongo shell or your C++ code take some time to come through, which is what you are seeing.

In production, if you have the oplog tailing set up properly you shouldn't see the delay.

Comment: How I can make its realtime ? I need to submit from c++ to mongo . Do I need to change something in mongodb ?

Comment: Are you in dev mode or production mode?

Comment: stupid queston but how I can see the mode and change it?  for mongo or meteor ?

Comment: If you are on your local computer you are in dev mode. If you have deployed it to a remote server it is in production mode.